# APC does not load when calling PHP from cli

Tags: php5

After installing APC on CentOS 5 via `pecl install apc`, APC does not load when PHP is called from the CLI (when called from apache, it loads without any problems).

The error I get is:

```
root@server [~]# php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/apc.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/apc.so: undefined symbol: pcre_exec in Unknown on line 0
```

I have searched the web for a solution, and have found many people have had this problem. However, I was unable to find a solution that worked for me.

Comment: Is pcre.h installed? libpcre I think is the parent library.

Comment: The package `pcre-devel` is installed via yum.

Comment: Why would it even make sense for it to run from the CLI?  IF APC isn't staying in memory, then it isn't going to do anything useful as a cache.

Comment: If PHP is called via mod_fcgid, then the PHP processes will be serving more than one request.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed the problem by removing APC via the pecl installer, then reinstalling it with the pear installer.

```
pecl uninstall apc
pear install pecl/apc
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `which php`, then `locate php`.  If you have multiple PHP binaries on your system (this can happen quite easily if you install one version via your package manager, then compile another via source), the extensions will not likely be compatible between versions.  Removing the incorrect PHP binary should allow this to work properly.

Comment: The output from `which php` is `/usr/bin/php`, but the output from `locate php` is too long to read, so I'll have to find other methods of finding other php binaries.

Comment: I was unable to find any other PHP binaries on the system.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add the following directive to your apc.ini file:

```
apc.enable_cli = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix for this relatively simple:

Copy the existing file `/etc/php.d/apc.ini` to `/tmp`

```
cp /etc/php.d/apc.ini /tmp
```

Remove the installed package

```
yum remove php-pecl-apc
```

Install the apc using pecl itself

```
pecl install apc
```

Move back file apc.ini

```
mv /tmp/apc.ini /etc/php.d/apc.ini
```